# Automatically resize a table based on the source data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table named `Table1` which is referenced by many cells in the workbook (i.e., target file).

The data in `Table1` is regularly manually copy-pasted from a source file: in the source file, I select the range of data, Ctrl+C, then go to the target file, select the top left cell of `Table1`, and Ctrl+V.

When the copied data has more rows than existing data in `Table1`, this manipulation automatically resizes well `Table1` to a bigger table. However, when the copied data has less rows than existing data in `Table1`, `Table1` is not automatically resized to a smaller table. I have to manually resize it.

Does anyone know if there is better manipulation to make this copy-paste automatically resize `Table1` based on the size of the copied data?

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple answer to your troubles:

***Reduce the table to the headers and one blank row. Just the one blank row. Either you have a single row, in which case, it simply fills it, or it will resize when you paste to precisely that many rows as are pasted. In no case does that situation of having fewer rows than the number already present in the table arise.***

You CANNOT, however, use `FILTER()` (specifically, as it was mentioned in another answer) or ANY `Spill` function. They DO NOT WORK in Tables, not at all or in any circumstance. You can certainly place a set of formulas to obtain a row's data from the source, then copy and paste it down as needed, but that's got the same difficulty as the practice in your post.

Edit:

Just noticed a note about existing formulas. They will still exist in the single row, and will populate down when you paste. So unlike `Ctrl-A, Delete`, you do not lose them with the above approach.

If you do not need the data in the table saved at any point, this handles everything as the single line is restored after every use by not saving.

Of course, if you DO need to save, or just want to save, sometime prior to your next use with new data, you will have to... manually... clear the data down to one row... So the problem would just be transferred in time.

You can start the macro recorder, reduce the Table to the single row, clear the data in the row (leaving formulas alone), and end the recording. If you assign that a shortcut or make a button and link the macro to it, Excel will do the work for you each time.

If you do not save after each use, it will come up with the single row each time, so no problems. If you do, then you cannot use VBA OnOpen or OnSave macro initiation since it would wipe out your work, so that just leaves the shortcut keypress or a button for easy use. (Or hunting up the macro with the mouse and initiating it, though that's harder. Not a lot! But you ARE looking for as little interaction here as possible is my feel.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest possible answer:

Wen you're about to paste; hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> hit <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>Delete</kbd> (the key) to remove the old data,
then paste the new (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

This of course assumes that you have the data alone on a sheet, no formulas intermixed.

Comment: In the table, I have some columns that hold formulas. If I remove all the old data, all the formula will be removed as well.

Comment: So, be more efficient ;-)  move the formula cells out of the data (-section) or why not even into a separate sheet? Much easier to change (replace) the data.

Answer (score 0):

[Table_Filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjlZn.png)

If you are using Office 365 make use of the Filter function to avoid manual issue or try on this:

```
=FILTER(Table1[#All],Table1[[#All],[Data1]]<>"","")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, I'm afraid you did not understand my question.